# android trying to round the bitmap corners

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have an imageView and and I'm trying to create rounded corners, tried all of the solutions from this post: [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)   But nothing worked.. Here's my XML

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_ImageHolder"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="Preview"

         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and that's how I set the ImageView using the method mentioned in the post I've linked above:

```
  byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
    if (byteArray != null) {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        preview.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        preview.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bmp));
```

The image is set correctly, but it keeps a rectangle.. Any ideas why it doesn't work?

**EDIT:** just found out that is doesn't work only when the layout holding the image has a fixed width/height.. Gotta think how to manage that. Thanks guys

Comment: check:[Android Recipe #1, image with rounded corners](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners) by [Romain Guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try with Below Code Snippet:

```
public static Bitmap GetCurveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // Bitmap myCoolBitmap = ... ; // <-- Your bitmap you
        // want rounded
        int w = bitmap.getWidth(), h = bitmap.getHeight();

        // We have to make sure our rounded corners have an
        // alpha channel in most cases
        Bitmap rounder = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(rounder);

        // We're going to apply this paint eventually using a
        // porter-duff xfer mode.
        // This will allow us to only overwrite certain pixels.
        // RED is arbitrary. This
        // could be any color that was fully opaque (alpha =
        // 255)
        Paint xferPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        xferPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

        // We're just reusing xferPaint to paint a normal
        // looking rounded box, the 20.f
        // is the amount we're rounding by.
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, w, h), 5.0f, 5.0f, xferPaint);

        // Now we apply the 'magic sauce' to the paint
        xferPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas resultCanvas = new Canvas(result);
        resultCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        resultCanvas.drawBitmap(rounder, 0, 0, xferPaint);

        return result;
    }
```

Hope it will Help you.

Comment: It can be achieved with less code and in a more efficient manner by calling Canvas.drawRect() and setting a BitmapShader on the Paint.

Comment: @RomainGuy: Yes,you are Right. Sorry i was not aware about it until now.your Suggestions is really nice and Straight Forward.i will apply your code when i need to apply rounded image in my project. Thanks. :)